# Hardware solution for screen capture

Tags: screen-capture

I'm trying to do some screen casts but no matter what application I try (Camtasia, FRAPS) the performance impact of the recording affects the quality of the animations I want to capture too much.

I use a top-end machine (i7, SSD etc.) so I doubt that I can do much about it and I have also tried several suggestions to tweak the performance (use different codecs etc.) but all to no avail.

Can anyone recommend a good hardware solution to capturing video? Ideally it would work with HDMI since my laptop only has a HDMI output.

Answer (score 1):

You can get capture cards which do that and don't affect your FPS in any way. This site will help you.

> http://www.videohelp.com/capturecards

Comment: +1 but unfortunately I am still not sure what I need to look for. there don't seem to be any USB/external capture devices which support HDMI input and the rest seem to be focused on capturing tv and don't seem to support high-quality capture of the screen itself.